# Running out of cards in Exploding Kitten

Tags: exploding-kittens, exploding-kittens-party-pack

I run out of cards as others were asking for it using the combo multiple times on me - does this mean I lost? or is drawing multiple action or combo cards allowed in drawing?

Comment: Do you mean you're running out of cards to _draw_, or that you run out of cards _in your hand_? The former is impossible (see the linked duplicate), the latter is quite possible but has no consequences for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to run out of cards. The last card in the deck is guaranteed to be an *Exploding Kitten*. You must either handle it using a *Defuse* (which would create a deck consisting of just an *Exploding Kitten*) or lose (which would cause the only other remaining player to win).

If you find yourself playing another turn immediately, you must contend with the *Exploding Kitten* a second time (unless you *Attack* or *Skip*).